# tftp (tftpd-hpa) file not found

Tags: linux, ftp, tftp

I've tried all of the things I've been able to find, but none of them match my issue. I have a tftpd-hpa server and I'm trying to pull a file from it with u-boot. I get "file not found" regardless of what I do. What I've tried

- -l -s -c -p options for tftpd-hpa
- changing the /tftpboot directory
- chowning everything as root:root
- full and relative paths (/tftpboot/myfile and myfile)

Despite tftpd not logging while having like 7 -v options, I can see the filename in tcpdump, and it is correct.

Is there something I'm missing? tftpd won't start as nobody, so everything is root right now.

edit: I wouldn't rule out corporate "safety measures" being unhappy with what I'm doing, however I have no way of proving it.

Comment: *"changing the /tftpboot directory"* -- What did you *"change"*?  FYI `/tftpboot` is not the default directory that is setup for tftp service.  Did you neglect to modify the default configuration, i.e. change the directory from `/var/lib/tftpboot`?

Comment: @sawdust I was changing the default configured directory I /etc/xinetd.d/tftp but just restarting `service tftpd-hpa` which I now realize might be wrong. Is there another configuration file somewhere?

Comment: *"Is there another configuration file somewhere?"* -- What distribution are you using?    Did you try a transfer using the default directory to see if that was still defined?  Did you try searching for files in **/etc** that contain a reference to the default directory?

Comment: That was it - the configuration file I was editing was the wrong one. I had a weird feeling when everything told me to edit the xinetd file - in hindsight I should have looked for a better config. Thank you!